# Why does SQL Server not delete entries when datetime field is expected to satisfy delete condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two columns in an events table, created by the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE events (date_time DATETIME, info VARCHAR(20));
```

The table was populated with some data. After executing the following command,

```
SELECT * FROM events;
```

the result obtained was:

```
date_time                   info
--------------------------------
2020-04-07 12:34:56.790     abcd
2020-04-07 12:34:56.890     efgh
```

Now, when deletion was done using the following command,

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE date_time < '2020-04-07 12:34:56.891';
```

it was expected that both rows of data would be deleted. However, only one was deleted. The row with date_time = '2020-04-07 12:34:56.890' and info = 'efgh' was retained.

Could anyone please explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision of `datetime` is 3 milliseconds.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explains:

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table.

So as a `datetime`, `'2020-04-07 12:34:56.891'` = `'2020-04-07 12:34:56.890'`.

To fix this, you should use [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), with a fractional seconds portion of at least 3.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e53e8d5695f8fd8018657b6e29bc928f) is a db<>fiddle.